# How can I collect wildcarded output files from subworkflows in parent Snakemake workflow?

Tags: snakemake

I have a Snakemake workflow with two subworkflows.

The two subworkflows produce a different number of output files, e.g.:

1. **Subworkflow 1** produces `results/subworkflow1/data.json`
2. **Subworkflow 2** produces `[results/subworkflow2/data1.json, results/subworkflow2/data2.json, results/subworkflow2/data3.json]`.

Within subworkflow 2, the data files are generated using wildcards which are known within the subworkflow.

Now I have a parent workflow in which I want to aggregate the filenames from both subworkflows in a single input value, but I can't get my mind around it.

Aggregation (as in the [example in the docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution)) doesn't work, as I cannot output just a `directory()` with wildcard file inputs it seems (input wildcards must be used in output). Also, the wildcards aren't available to me in the parent workflow rule.

Checkpoint try from subworkflow 2:

```py
rule do_files:  # Doesn't work with either rule or checkpoint with aggregation
    input:
        input_json = f'{MY_DIR}/{{file_name}}.json',
    output:
        output_json = f'{RESULTS_DIR}result-{{file_name}}.json',
        # output_dir = directory(RESULTS_DIR)  # <---------- Doesn't work
```

In parent workflow I'm trying:

```py
rule all:
    input:
        rules.subworkflow2_do_files.output,
    default_target: True
```

This gets me the following error message:

```bash
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'file_name'
```

I've tried `directory()`-style aggregation as noted in the docs, but because I'm not using the same wildcards in output as in input, this breaks.